# PyAPNs version 1.1.2 doesn’t have enhanced keyword?

Tags: python, pip, package, easy-install, pyapns

I’m sure this is obvious, but I’m missing it.  I’ve installed PyAPNs via pip:

```
# pip install apns
```

Then when I try to use the “enhanced” flag in APNs, it’s not there.

```
# python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 11 2013, 18:34:29) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from apns import APNs
>>> server = APNs(use_sandbox=True, cert_file=“/mydir/apns-dev-cert.pem", key_file=“/mydir/apns-dev-key.pem", enhanced=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'enhanced'
>>>
```

And sure enough the 1.1.2 version that pip installed doesn’t have that keyword.  But I thought this was the latest released version in the PyAPNs repository https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs.

I want to use the ‘enhanced’ keyword, for error checking.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version 1.1.2 that is currently available on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/apns) doesn't provide an `enhanced` argument for `APNs` class (see [source](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/blob/1.1.2/apns.py#L46)).

If you want this functionality, install the module directly from github (master branch):

```
pip install git+https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs.git
```

Note that they haven't updated the package version in [`setup.py`](https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/blob/master/setup.py#L13), so, if you have this module installed already, uninstall it first, then install it from github:

```
pip uninstall apns
pip install git+https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs.git
```

Comment: You win the speed record.  Thank you!

Comment: @mobopro thanks, nope, 4 minutes to answer is usually really slow for SO :)

Answer (score 0):

if you want more error-free version, you may try this fork

`pip install git+https://github.com/jimhorng/PyAPNs.git`

which resolved errors from long idle connections: 
https://github.com/djacobs/PyAPNs/issues/94